# Using SELECT TOP from one column, then sorting on a different column

Tags: sql-server, syntax, subquery

I'm using SQL Server 2005, and I want to query for the vendors generating the most revenue, sorted by the vendor's name.  Below is the query I have tried.  The inner subquery gets the 15 largest vendors sorted by revenue, and I try to order *those* results by the vendor name.

```
SELECT Revenue, VendorName
FROM (
  SELECT TOP 15
         SUM(po.POTotal) AS Revenue
       , Vendors.VendorName AS VendorName
  FROM PurchaseOrders po
  INNER JOIN Vendors ON po.Vendor_ID = Vendors.Vendor_ID
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY Vendors.VendorName
  ORDER BY Revenue DESC
)
ORDER BY VendorName ASC
```

But this gives me an error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Is there another way to do this?  I think this might be possible with a view, but I'd prefer not to do it that way.

---

<sup>I apologize if this is a duplicate, I don't even know what to search for to see if this has already been asked.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an alias for the subquery:

```
SELECT Revenue, VendorName
FROM (SELECT TOP 15         
        SUM(po.POTotal) AS Revenue, 
        v.VendorName AS VendorName  
      FROM PurchaseOrders po  
        JOIN Vendors v 
          ON po.Vendor_ID = v.Vendor_ID 
      WHERE ... 
      GROUP BY v.VendorName  
      ORDER BY Revenue DESC) Z
ORDER BY VendorName ASC
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to give your derived table an alias:

```
  ...
  ORDER BY Revenue DESC
) AS DerivedTable
ORDER BY VendorName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with a CTE:

```
WITH revenue (Revenue, VendorName)
AS
(SELECT TOP 15 SUM(po.POTotal) AS Revenue, Vendors.VendorName AS VendorName  
FROM PurchaseOrders po  
INNER JOIN Vendors 
ON po.Vendor_ID = Vendors.Vendor_ID  
WHERE ...  
GROUP BY Vendors.VendorName  
ORDER BY Revenue DESC)
SELECT Revenue, VendorName
FROM revenue
ORDER BY VendorName ASC
```

Comment: thanks this worked too. i'm sticking with the other syntax though, it's a little more clear to me

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without a sub-query if you like --

```
SELECT sum(po.POTotal) as Revenue, vendors.VendorName
FROM   PurchaseOrders po  INNER JOIN Vendors ON po.Vendor_ID = Vendors.Vendor_ID  
WHERE ...  
GROUP BY Vendors.VendorName  
ORDER BY sum(po.POTotal) DESC, VendorName ASC
```

Try that and see if it works - we do the same sort of thing here and this was our solution...

Comment: doesn't work.  the secondary sort by vendor name will only happen if two vendors share exactly the same order total (which will rarely happen)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, forgot the TOP 15 in the query above - it needs to go just befor the sum() aggregate function.